# Using PHPUnit... how can I know which test return an Exception?

Tags: php, phpunit

I have set `verbose="true"` and try to run with `--debug --verbose --testdox` basically anything I searched across the Internet.

However, I am still dissatisfied with the result:

```
Configuration read from /phpunit.xml

EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE..EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE   61 / 2244 (  2%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  122 / 2244 (  5%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE...  183 / 2244 (  8%)
...........EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  244 / 2244 ( 10%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  305 / 2244 ( 13%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE..EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  366 / 2244 ( 16%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  427 / 2244 ( 19%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  488 / 2244 ( 21%)
EEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  549 / 2244 ( 24%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEE.EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  610 / 2244 ( 27%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  671 / 2244 ( 29%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  732 / 2244 ( 32%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE....  793 / 2244 ( 35%)
..EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE............EEEEEEEEEEE  854 / 2244 ( 38%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE  915 / 2244 ( 40%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEE................................................  976 / 2244 ( 43%)
............E................................................ 1037 / 2244 ( 46%)
........................................................EEEEE 1098 / 2244 ( 48%)
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE................. 1159 / 2244 ( 51%)
...........................................................E. 1220 / 2244 ( 54%)
E............................................................ 1281 / 2244 ( 57%)
..........................EE...............E................. 1342 / 2244 ( 59%)
............................................................. 1403 / 2244 ( 62%)
............................................................. 1464 / 2244 ( 65%)
............................................................. 1525 / 2244 ( 67%)
..................................PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function hello_world() in NotTest.php:73
Stack trace:
#0 Something.php(272): lolz('qwe', 'asd...', 'jkf...')
#1 Something.php(40): function('qwe')
#2 Something.php(99): function
```

It shows nothing about which tests failed and which file is currently in progress. That, and especially **I want to know which test cause the above exception**.

Comment: You do not get any details because PHP exits with a fatal error. Try `--stop-on-error` to have PHPUnit stop, and report details, on the first error.

Comment: I see...! Write down below and I will mark it! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not get any details because PHP exits with a fatal error. Try --stop-on-error to have PHPUnit stop, and report details, on the first error.